# xml parsing with jquery in IE problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have below example made in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/4Gdjg/1/) which works perfectly in Firefox 6 and chrome but not in IE8. How can I resolve this issue?

```
var xml = "<Response>  <isSuccess>true</isSuccess>  <operation>viewall</operation> <message>No configurations were found for this project</message></Response>";

alert($(xml).find('message').text());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `.parseXML`

```
var xml = "<Response>  <isSuccess>true</isSuccess>  <operation>viewall</operation> <message>No configurations were found for this project</message></Response>";

    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $title = $xml.find( "message" ).text();

alert($title);
```

**here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/szVKD/1/**

[**jquery parse xml**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)